# Svnmerge and a file replaced with a directory

Tags: svn, branch, svn-merge

I'm using svnmerge.py to manage our repository. In trunk, file X has been replaced a directory. When trying to merge this to a branch, I get the error:

svn: Can't replace 'X' with a node of a differing type; the deletion must be committed and the parent updated before adding 'X'
svn: Error reading spooled REPORT request response

I deleted X on the branch, and committed, but the same error persists. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you can do partial merges in SVN. Have you tried to merge up to the revision in which X was deleted, and then merge the resting revisions?

Comment: I got someone else to do it, and it worked for them, so I can't test your suggestion. But it sounds like it could work, and there's no better idea, so I'm marking this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Perform #svn up and then perfrom #svn add